# Hearing in Rails Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favorites

New to Rails, trying to add a favorites, using hearts on posts in my app and dont know why I'm getting this sytax error. Have followed the tutorial step by step.Is this somethong obvious ?

/Users/leehumphreys/Desktop/with hearts favorites/app/views/rooms/show.html.erb:292: unterminated string meets end of file /Users/leehumphreys/Desktop/with hearts favorites/app/views/rooms/show.html.erb:292: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'

```
 <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
  <%= room.title %>
  <%= div_for room do %>
     render "hearts/button”, room: room 
    <% end %>
  <% end %
```

Actually getting the error at <% @rooms.each do |room| %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

```
<% room.title %>
```

won't do anything because you need to output the result, thus:

```
<%= room.title %>
```

Then, you have one too many `end`.  You only need to close one bock:

```
<%= room.title %>
<%= div_for room do %>
  <%= render partial: "hearts/button”, locals: { room: room } %>
<% end %>
```

Basically, your `end` is a completion for `do`. Every `do` starts a block, which must end with an `end`.

Also note your render can be simplified as such:

```
render "hearts/button”, room: room
```

**Update after comment to answer:**

```
<% @rooms.each do |room| %>
  <%= room.title %>
  <%= div_for room do %>
    <%= render "hearts/button”, room: room  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I suggest you take a look at some erb tutorial, [this one for example](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb).

Comment: thanks for the help ecoologic, I missed copying and pasting the                   <% @rooms.each do |room| %> line and now getting an error there.

Comment: @lee if you use another `do` (in the `each` line), you'll need another `end`. Render must be _interpolated_.  If you like the answer please tick it as "answered", there should be a green tick button on the top left side of the answer, under the plus votes.  Happy hacking